# How to include data from foreign key object in Django ORM query?

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-models, django-orm

I'm trying to query for an object in my DB, and get data from another object that shares a Foreign Key relationship.

For example, if I have these models:

```
class Book(models.Model):
   language = models.ForeignKey('Language')
   ...

class Language(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
```

I want to query these models and get a QuerySet of books, then return the books via an API.

In raw SQL I would do something akin to:

```
SELECT book, language.name
FROM book
JOIN ....
```

Is there any way to accomplish this with the Django ORM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using django rest framework for the API, You can do this by using serializer Method field

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    language = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ['id', 'language']
    def get_language(self,obj)
       return obj.language.name
```

Another way to do this is adding  a property field to Book Model

```
   @property
   def language(self):
       return self.language.name
```

Now if you do book_obj.language ,You can get the name in language model

Comment: Awesome, the Serializer field did the trick! Thanks very much.